# Beautifulsoup find_all missing items

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I checked the response.text by saving it into the file and it's all good. I can see the span id = 'productTitle'. When I try to filter like in the code below I get an empty string. I tried to filter only by 'span' and for some reason I get partial result only(product title is missing).

```
headers = {
       'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0',
       'Accept':'*/*',
       'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
       'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
       'Connection':'keep-alive'
   }
r = requests.get(product_url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('span')
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the HTML code it's difficult to reproduce the problem and give a full answer.

try replacing `'html.parser'` with `'lxml'`